# take picture from Input field and convert to base64

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to be able to take picture from PC and uploaded to server. So far I have managed to take a picture from a div, convert it to base64 and send it to server side. This works without a problem.

My HTML:

```
  <img src="AvatarIMG/Goofy.jpg" id="img" width="100" height="100">
```

My JavaScript:

```
  $('#but_upload').click(function () {
            var c = document.createElement('canvas');
            var img = document.getElementById('img');
            c.height = img.naturalHeight;
            c.width = img.naturalWidth;
            var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
            console.log(ctx);
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, c.width, c.height, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            var base64String = c.toDataURL();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Avatar',
                method: 'PUT', 
                contentType: 'application/json',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '
                        + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")
                },
                dataType: "text",
                data: JSON.stringify(base64String),
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (jQXHR) {
                }
            });
        });
```

However i want to be able to pick a picture from my local computer and then upload it but so far no luck... This is what I have tried...

My HTML:

```
 <input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" />
```

My JavaScript:

```
 $('#but_upload').click(function () {

            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.height = 30;
            img.width = 20;

            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                img.src = oFREvent.target.result;
            };

            var c = document.createElement('canvas');
            c.height = img.naturalHeight;
            c.width = img.naturalWidth;
            var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, c.width, c.height, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            var base64String = c.toDataURL();



            $.ajax({
                url: 'Avatar',
                method: 'PUT', 
                contentType: 'application/json',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '
                        + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")
                },
                dataType: "text",
                data: JSON.stringify(base64String),
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (jQXHR) {
                }
            });
        });
```

Some help pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need to wait for `img.onload`, because you are trying to draw it onto the canvas before the image even loads.

```js
$('#but_upload').click(function() {

  var img = document.createElement("img");

  var oFReader = new FileReader();
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

  oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
    img.src = oFREvent.target.result;
  };

  img.onload = function() {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.height = img.naturalHeight;
    c.width = img.naturalWidth;
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, c.width, c.height, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    var base64String = c.toDataURL();
    console.log(base64String);
    // upload your stuff
  }


  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" />
  <input id="but_upload" type="submit" />
</form>
```

On the other hand, since `FileReader` reads as a `DataURL`, you could simply use what it has already read

```js
$('#but_upload').click(function() {

  var img = document.createElement("img");

  var oFReader = new FileReader();
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

  oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
    img.src = oFREvent.target.result;
    var base64String = oFREvent.target.result;
    console.log(base64String);
    // do your uploading stuff here
  };


  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" />
  <input id="but_upload" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hay my man this works... Finally! Thanks a lot man. If it is not too much, can I ask you for one more favor? How to make the picture that I send to be always  the size, Width: 20, Height 20. If it is not too much. Thanks anyway and have a nice day dude.

Comment: In the first example just change this... c.height = 20;
c.width = 20; ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight, 0, 0, 20, 20,); The uploaded picture now will be 20 x 20;